# ZTE Open don't boot after flash to Firefox OS 1.2

Tags: firefox-os

I have ZTE Open with custom ROM Boot2Gecko 1.3.0.0-prerelease (Git 2013-10-19 22:09:07 d544afff51)

I'm building B2G v.1.2.

```
BRANCH=v1.2 ./config.sh inari
./build
```

Build finishes successful. 
I'm flashing and see next:

```
./flash.sh 
< waiting for device >
erasing 'cache'...
OKAY [  0.530s]
finished. total time: 0.530s
erasing 'userdata'...
OKAY [  1.405s]
finished. total time: 1.405s
sending 'userdata' (55044 KB)...
OKAY [  5.074s]
writing 'userdata'...
OKAY [ 10.051s]
finished. total time: 15.125s
sending 'system' (81724 KB)...
OKAY [  7.507s]
writing 'system'...
OKAY [ 14.973s]
finished. total time: 22.479s
rebooting...

finished. total time: 0.001s
Attempting to set the time on the device
time 1384896807 -> 1384896807.0
```

But my phone is frizzed on logoscreen

`adb shell dmesg` returns next: https://gist.github.com/blackbass1988/7559973

I'm building on MacosX 10.9

Strange, why build says that everything ok, but not ok

Comment: Are you getting a black screen that is otherwise responsive? (adb fastboot work, home button works, power button work) Here is a bug I've opened: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=958903
You can get dmesg there, at first glance they didn't appear to be too similar.

Answer (score 1):

You used the adapted boot.img? Without this you will not be able to get a working system, just by using the build instructions on MDN. Here are some blogs that describe the build process:

- https://blog.non.co.il/index.php/zte-open-phone-upgrading-to-firefoxos-1-1-how-to/
- http://rowehl.com/blog/2013/10/24/firefoxos-1-dot-2-on-zte-open/
- http://sl.edujose.org/2013/10/adapted-boot-image-for-use-with-b2g.html

Comment: Yes, I tried with this boot and without these. Here is dmesg with custom boot https://gist.github.com/blackbass1988/7571685

Answer (score 0):

Odd.  Try reseting the cache from the system recovery.
ie : reboot, hold the power+volume up while it's restarting and you should get to the system recovery.  move down to "wipe cache partition" w/ the volume down button and hit power button to confirm.  Then reboot the device again and see if it starts up.